# C4 passing data between views

Tags: class, methods, subclass, c4

Hei,
I am using different subclasses for the different view in my application. for that I am now trying to pass a C4Image from one function to another.
My code is as follows:
**in TakePhoto.m**

```
cropPhoto= [CropPhoto new];
cropPhoto.canvas.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.canvas.width, self.canvas.height);
cropPhoto.canvas.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[cropPhoto setup:img];

cropPhoto.mainCanvas=self.canvas;
[self.canvas addSubview:cropPhoto.canvas];
```

img is declared as a C4Image in the TakePhoto.h

**in CropPhoto.m** I declared the setup function like this

```
-(void) setup:(C4Image)image{
//some code here 
}
```

In the TakePhoto.m I'm getting the error
"No visible @interface for 'CropPhoto' declares the selector 'setup'."
I'm doing pretty much the same thing within the one subclass passing NSUIntegers and there it works. So is there anything else I need to do for C4Images or because I'm passing values between subclasses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `-(void)setup:(C4Image *)image;` needs to be declared n the `.h` file of the class, otherwise no other objects will be able to call it.

You .h should look something like:

```
@interface CropPhoto 
-(void)setup:(C4Image *)image;
@end
```

The reason for this is that `setup:(C4image*)...` is a custom method that *you* are implementing on your own, so you need to make it visible.

**There could be a lot of other reasons as well.*** Check out the following answers for different scenarios that generate the same issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10387710/1218605

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14155178/1218605

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13001909/1218605